# Can't Append strings from txt file

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I am trying to read a local file called start.txt

If I reach a point where the first line is `nextpage`, it'll do something but if isn't it will append to a textarea. However it gives me an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'inputtext' of undefined (23:44:44:520 | error, javascript)
    at  (public_html/index.html:12:50)`

The file that I am trying to read is in the same folder as the index.html file. I am fairly new to HTML, AJAX and JavaScript so I might possibly just not know what the frak I am doing!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.2.4/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var inputarea = document.textareaform.inputtext.value;
            txtFile.open("GET", "http://localhost/start.txt", true);
            txtFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
                // Makes sure the document is ready to parse.
                if(txtFile.readyState === 4) {
                    // Makes sure it's found the file.
                    if(txtFile.status === 200) {
                        allText = txtFile.responseText;
                        // Will separate each line into an array
                        lines = txtFile.responseText.split("\n");
                        for(i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                            var s = lines[i];
                            if(s.indexOf("nextpage") > -1) {
                                // Line is there

                            } else {
                                // Line is not there
                                inputarea += s;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            txtfile.send(null);
        </script>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="textareaform">
            <textarea name="fileoutput" rows="4" cols="20" readonly="readonly">

            </textarea>
        </form>

        <div>TODO write content</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you use a DOM library ? http://microjs.com

Comment: @cept0 Because I am a novice. What is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's looking for a `textarea` named "inputtext", and you've named it "fileoutput".

Try renaming your textarea to "inputtext":

```
<textarea name="inputtext" rows="4" cols="20" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
```

**or**

define your variable differently:

```
var inputarea = document.textareaform.fileoutput.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

change the var inputarea declartion to this.

```
var inputArea = document.getElementsByName('fileoutput');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I use that further down though. Do I have to change that as well?